# Case sensitive coldfusion IF statements

Tags: coldfusion, case-sensitive

I have a coldfusion application running right now with a login that sends a query to the database looking for a row with the same username and password as what was entered into the form.

Curently, it is completely non-case sensitive. However, I would like to add case sensitivity to the password field, so that users have to have the exact password. Is there a way to do a case sensitive IF statement in coldfusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hash() both values and compare the hashes.

```
<cfif Hash( DBPassword ) EQ Hash( SubmittedPassword )>
      <!--- Login Code --->
 </cfif>
```

Also, you shouldn't be storing passwords as plain-text in the databases as is.

Comment: +1. Though `compare` is probably the function you are looking for, storing passwords in plain text is unwise. Better to store a hashed version in your db table and use something like `WHERE Password = <cfqueryparam value="#Hash(form.password)#" ..>`

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned here:
http://www.irt.org/script/3018.htm

seems you can use:

```
<cfif Compare(string1,string2) eq "0">...</cfif>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

If your database supports case-sensitivity, set your table to use a case-sensitive collation - then your user lookup query will make case-sensitive comparison of stored and provided username/password. You won't have to do any post-query string comparison using CF then (1 less process to run = good :)

+1 to Leigh's caution about storing passwords in plain-text.

Comment: Yep, or if you do not want to permanently change it, you could also use [COLLATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html) on a per comparison basis.